# How to put a character in the middle of a string in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have emails like this in the users table.

`TestMail20000@gmail.com`

I need to change it like this.

`TestMail+20000@gmail.com`

It means need to add `+` sign between the number and the srtings. how can I do that?

Comment: Use [REGEXP_REPLACE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace)

Comment: How about if the email value is like this `Test200Mail2000@gmail.com`? How about if there's a special character in between? Please provide all possible variation of email value and please run `SELECT version();` to check your MySQL version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your strings follow that exact pattern, i.e., always starting with `TestMail`, then you could just use `REPLACE()` documented [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace).

```
UPDATE USERS_TABLE
   SET EMAIL_ADDRESS = REPLACE(EMAIL_ADDRESS, 'TestMail', 'TestMail+')
 WHERE EMAIL_ADDRESS LIKE ('TestMail%);
```

Otherwise, you might need to get more complex with `REGEXP_REPLACE()`, e.g.,

```
UPDATE USERS_TABLE
   SET EMAIL_ADDRESS = REGEXP_REPLACE(EMAIL_ADDRESS, '^:alpha:', 'TestMail+')
WHERE EMAIL_ADDRESS LIKE ('TestMail%);
```

But I'll assume the format is as you described for your "TestMail" users.